# Is Tor Browser vulnerable to WebRTC leak?

Tags: web-browser, tor, vulnerability

If so, which are all the possible solutions to the problem?
Are there similar issues to be aware of?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test on your own: https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/ - or at least try to use google next time.

Comment: I am not able to mention you, but I hope you will read the comment anyway. I have not already downloaded the Tor Browser, and on google I found discordant asnwers. That is way I decided to ask here. Can you answer with a less cryptic "yes or no", please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tor is safe against WebRTC leaking.